# Pharo ZnSecureServer - SSL Exception: accept failed [code:-5]

Tags: pharo

Environment: Pharo 8.0 64bit on macOS Catalina 10.15.4.

Started a secure server like so:

```
(ZnSecureServer on: 8443)
    certificate: '/Users/meme/pharo_cert/server.pem';
    logToTranscript;
    start;
    yourself.
```

When I point my browser (Safari, Chrome or FF), Pharo throws this error:

```
Error: SSL Exception: accept failed [code: -5]
```

from:

```
accept
    "Do the SSL server handshake."
    | count result |
    self resetEncryptedBuffers.
    count := 0.
    connecting := true.
    [ self sslSession isConnected ] whileFalse: [
        count := self readEncryptedBytes: in startingAt: 1 count: in size.
        result := self sslSession accept: in from: 1 to: count into: out.
        result < -1 ifTrue: [ 
            ^ self sslException: 'accept failed' code: result ].
        result > 0 ifTrue: [ 
            self flushEncryptedBytes: out startingAt: 1 count: result ] ].
    connecting := false
```

Thoughts? 
My self-signed certificate works fine when run using openssl:

```
( openssl s_server -accept 8443 -cert server.pem -WWW )
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are using a certificate format/type that is not supported